# Incorrectly reading .dat file in c++

Tags: c++, file

I am new to c++ and have gotten to a module about file i/o. I have copied the example from my textbook verbatim and it does not seem to work as expected and I am not sure what the problem could be; there are no errors that are output from the program.

I have tried different variations and settled on this example:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string f = "marks.dat"; ifstream file;


int main() {
    int first = 0;
    file.open(f);
    if(file.is_open()){
        file >> first;
        cout << first;
    } else {
    cout << "file has failed to open";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The .dat file is in the folder Assignment3.1 from which the .cpp file is compiled. The check for "file.is_open()" is false and I am not sure what the issue is.

The output of my code is as follows:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btKZ7.png)

EDIT: I have included a declaration for first = 0; and included a file.is_open();

EDIT: the pwd for the folder is: 
/Users/stjohn/Documents/cpp/Assignment3.1

Comment: Can you store the absolute path of the .dat file in string f.

Comment: 1) `.cpp` is not executed, it's compiled 2) executable file is not executed from folder `Assignment3.1` and that's why you can't read from data file

Comment: `but the check returns False` then you are not reading your file

Comment: @GrzegorzAdamKowalski thank you for the slightly valuable input.

Comment: @KillzoneKid thank you for the slightly valuable input.

Comment: @GrzegorzAdamKowalski I have pasted the .dat file within the /bin/Debug/ folder with no success. Seems that explicitly coding the full directory path is the only way...

Answer (score 1):

I think file is not being read properly. You are getting random number from variable first. Try to initialise first to zero and then see output. You should understand what is going on.

first=0;

Comment: This does solve the fact that I was getting different outputs each time I ran the program but does not solve the inability to read the .dat file

Comment: Does file exist in same folder where program is being run?

Answer (score 1):

The current file is not being read because it is not contained within the correct directory from which the program executes. By using the full file path in the string declaration the program will be able to read the file.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string f = "/Users/stjohn/Documents/cpp/Assignment3.1/marks.dat"; ifstream file;


int main() {
    int first = 0;
    file.open(f);
    if(file.is_open()){
        file >> first;
        cout << first;
    } else {
    cout << "file has failed to open";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on screenshots, I assume you're using Code::Blocks for MacOS. Set the working directory in Project > Properties > Build Target > Execution Working Directory.